# Add new button in has_many in activeadmin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, nested-form-for

```
f.has_many :offers,heading: 'Offers' do |item|
  item.input :quantity
  item.input :offer_type_id, :prompt => 'Select Offer Type', :as => :select, :collection => OfferType.all.map{|m| [m.title, m.id]}
    item.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean
end
```

It works fine and has_many association created. I want that the button for adding associated data automatically clicked or open when I load page.

```
Add new Offer
```

Instead that user click on it for first associated data it automatically clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AA controller block you need yo `build` offer - it will add the offer's fields to the form:

```
controller do
  def new
    super do
      resource.offers.build
    end
  end
end
```